# iOS UI automation: Handling alertViews when the length of textbox is exceeded

Tags: ios, automation

I am very new to this iOS auto tool. 
I have a text-box with length is 20 letters. When I trying to type more than 20, such as 21 letters, an error is shown up like: "length is exceeded", having only one "OK" button , after get this error, just tap on OK button to dismiss this pop up, and if wanna save change, tap on Save button.
My script like this:

```
target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().tableViews()[2].cells()[0].tap();// name 

target.frontMostApp().keyboard().typeString("mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmn");

 target.delay( 5 );

 UIATarget.onAlert = function onAlert(alert){

         var title = alert.name();

         UIALogger.logWarning("Alert with title' " + title + " ' encountered!");

    if (title == "Error") {

        alert.buttons()["OK"].tap();

         return true; // bypass default handler

         }

        return false; // use default handler

    }   


 target.frontMostApp().navigationBar().buttons()["Save"].tap()
```

But the script stops right after typing more than 20 letters (Line 2) and cant move to the next line. 
So anyone please give me an idea about this. Thank so much.

Comment: one thing,

basically "everyone" uses https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD